# .htaccess files - potential conflict?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, vbulletin

I am going live with my new Wordpress site tomorrow and I've been reading that wordpress can conflict with vbulletin in terms of their .htaccess files.

This is my forum .htaccess at /home/mysite/public_html/forum:

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

# Comment the following line (add '#' at the beginning)
# to disable mod_rewrite functions.
# Please note: you still need to disable the hack in
# the vBSEO control panel to stop url rewrites.
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require the Rewritebase directive to be
# enabled (remove '#' at the beginning to activate)
# Please note: when enabled, you must include the path
# to your root vB folder (i.e. RewriteBase /forums/)
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.net/forum/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$
vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(admincp/|modcp/|cron|vbseo_sitemap)
RewriteRule ^((archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?)?)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
!^(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images)/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]


<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#php_flag suhosin.cookie.encrypt Off
#php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 2048
#php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 2048

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

and this will likely be my wordpress htaccess sitting at /home/mysite/public_html/

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php

deny from 117.194.192.222
deny from 85.195.123.
deny from 220.237.99.16
deny from 144.140.22.68
deny from 213.166.17.22
deny from 213.166.17.21
deny from 213.166.17.18
deny from 116.71.74.209
deny from 59.98.160.41
deny from 124.124.254.203
deny from 173.45.114.178
deny from 203.82.100.162
deny from 66.90.101.179
deny from 119.155.18.94
deny from 80.249.48.130
deny from 80.249.48.131
deny from 80.249.48.132
deny from 80.249.48.133
deny from 80.249.48.134
deny from 80.249.48.135
deny from 80.249.48.136
deny from 80.249.48.137
deny from 80.249.48.138
deny from 80.249.48.139
deny from 80.249.48.140

# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I was wondering if anyone sees any potential conflicts there that may cause
issues for vbulletin or wordpress?

Comment: Nothing jumps out as a possible conflict. Why not try it and see if anything breaks?

Comment: I suggest you to install vbulletin in a subdomain such as forum.yourdomain.com. If wordpress generate a page "/forum/.." like this it will be a conflict, so your wordpress site will be dominant in this kind of situation.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I can't test it until Wordpress is live though can I?

Comment: Thanks Mehmet, I don't want to change the URLs of the forum though and want it to work as is.